# Proving a bound for the leading coefficient of a polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, chebyshev-polynomials

Show that every real polynomial $x\in C[a,b]$ of degree $n\ge 1$ with leading term $\beta_n t^n$ satisfies $$||x||\ge |\beta_n|\frac{(b-a)^n}{2^{2n-1}}.$$

I am having difficulty proving this. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Minimal_.E2.88.9E-norm) on wikipedia it is shown how to do this when $a=-1$ and $b=1$, but how can it be shown for arbitrary $a$ and $b$?

Comment: This is not very clear, shouldn't there be a polynomial $p(x)$ somewhere? And should there be an $x$ on both sides of your inequality?

Comment: Hint: linearly map $[a,b]$ to $[-1,1]\,$, then divide by the leading coefficient and apply the result from the link.